# How to create a nested object list in java 8?

Tags: java, spring, java-8

This is how I declare `xlist`:

```
List<List<Object>> xlist = new ArrayList<>(); 
xlist.add(xvalueList1); 
xlist.add(xvalueList2); 
xlist.add(xvalueList3);
```

my ylist contains 2018,2019 and 2020

And this is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < yearsList.size(); i++) {
    if (yearsList.get(i).intValue() == model.getYear().intValue()) {
        xlist.get(i).add(Constants.WEEK + model.getStep());
    }
}
```

I want my output to be :
{{2018,2018,2018},{2019,2019},{2020}}

so far this is what I have :

```
List<List<Objects>> list =
        yearsList.stream()
               .filter(year-> year == model.getYear().intValue())
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: What is your xlist?

Comment: List<List<Object>> xlist = new ArrayList<>();
      xlist.add(xvalueList1);
      xlist.add(xvalueList2);
      xlist.add(xvalueList3);

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
List<Integer> years = Arrays.asList(2020, 2019, 2018);      
List<List<Integer>> result = IntStream.range(0, years.size())
 .mapToObj(i ->  Collections.nCopies(i+1, years.get(i)))
 .sorted((a, b) -> b.size() - a.size())
 .collect(Collectors.toList());     
 System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: I want to filter it by this condition year-> year == model.getYear().intValue() and add it to my result nested list only if the year satisfies it.

Comment: Here is what i have so far : yearsList.stream().filter(year-> year ==
   metricModel.getYear().intValue()).IntStream.range(0, yearsList.size()).mapToObj(i -> ylist.get(i).add(merchValue)));

Comment: You got to describe your requirement clearly (not just the filter). At the moment is it unclear.